# Getting ERROR 000800 keyword used is not member of list of acceptable keywords from ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.0, network-analyst, error-000800

I'm trying to use arcpy.AddFieldToAnalysisLayer_na using a network analysis layer

```py
def fonction(network):
 in_network_dataset = network
 out_network_analysis_layer = "Best_Route"
 impedance_attribute = "length"
 field_name = "IIDTSTARCO"
 field_type = "LONG"

#I create my network analysis layer
 arcpy.MakeRouteLayer_na(in_network_dataset,out_network_analysis_layer,impedance_attribute)

#and then I want to add a field to PolylineBarriers sublayer

 arcpy.AddFieldToAnalysisLayer_na(out_network_analysis_layer, "PolylineBarriers", field_name, field_type)
```

When I run the script I get the following error:

```py
ERROR 000800: The value is not a member of  Stops | Barriers | Routes | PolylineBarriers | PolygonBarriers
```

while "PolylineBarriers" is in the list

Comment: Are you really using ArcGIS 10.0, as the question is tagged?  That is *really* ancient software (10.2.2 was recently retired), which makes it unlikely that anyone else could use it to test the reproducibility of your problem.  If you are using something more current, then please [Edit] the question to specify the exact software release.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately, I still use ArcGIS 10.0

Comment: Then all you can do is apply SP5 and hope it's magically fixed.